# Performance issues with a Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat application

Tags: spring, performance, hibernate, tomcat

I have a server running the Spring/Hibernate/Tomcat stack.
After a while the server starts to respond slowly and restarting the tomcat usually solves this.
Might this be some kind of memory leak?
Are there any tweaks I can do to enhance the performance?
Which tools can I use to profile the server and try to find the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Use a memory profiler to see what happens. Make sure you have proper transaction management in place, don't use `openSession` or `getSession` on the hibernate template to get a session.

Comment: increase your heap memory of TOMCAT and try .

Comment: why not use getSession or openSession?